# What are possible use of exec command?

Tags: command-line

I am learning `exec` command. I know that the `exec` command replaces the process which has started it. So that isn't possible to return to the process which is replaced by `exec` command.

One could say that it's purpose is to make it impossible to return to the process which started it.

**But what are other uses for having something like `exec` available as a command?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)

Comment: from the wikipedia article: "Wrapper scripts often use this command to run a program (either directly or through an interpreter or virtual machine) after setting environment variables or other configuration."

Comment: more suitable for [cs.se]

Comment: Personally, I find `exec ssh server-that-does-byobu-on-login.example.com` to be very pleasing, in that ^A^D shuts down the terminal altogether. (More generally, `exec byobu` (or `exec screen`, `exec tmux`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### In wrapper script

`exec` is used mainly in wrapper scripts.

If you want to modify the environment for a program before executing the main program, you'd often write an script and at the end of it start the main program. But there is no need for the script to stay in memory at that time. So, `exec` is used in these cases so that, the main program can replace the mother script.

Here is a practical example of it. It's `mate-terminal.wrapper` script comes with mate-terminal. It starts the `mate-terminal` with some extra arguments by checking user's environments.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $login=0;

while ($opt = shift(@ARGV))
{
    if ($opt eq '-display')
    {
        $ENV{'DISPLAY'} = shift(@ARGV);
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-name')
    {
        $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        push(@args, "--window-with-profile=$arg");
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-n')
    {
        # Accept but ignore
        print STDERR "$0: to set an icon, please use -name <profile> and set a profile icon\n"
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-T' || $opt eq '-title')
    {
        push(@args, '-t', shift(@ARGV));
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-ls')
    {
        $login = 1;
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '+ls')
    {
        $login = 0;
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-geometry')
    {
        $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        push(@args, "--geometry=$arg");
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-fn')
    {
        $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        push(@args, "--font=$arg");
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-fg')
    {
        $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        push(@args, "--foreground=$arg");
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-bg')
    {
        $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        push(@args, "--background=$arg");
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-tn')
    {
       $arg = shift(@ARGV);
       push(@args, "--termname=$arg");
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-e')
    {
        $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        if (@ARGV)
        {
            push(@args, '-x', $arg, @ARGV);
            last;
        }
        else
        {
            push(@args, '-e', $arg);
        }
        last;
    }
    elsif ($opt eq '-h' || $opt eq '--help')
    {
        push(@args, '--help');
    }
}
if ($login == 1)
{
    @args = ('--login', @args);
}
exec('mate-terminal',@args);
```

The point to notice here is, there is an `exec` call, which replaces this script in memory.

Here is a similar question answered in Unix & Linux StackExchange Site - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270929/19288

#### To redirect file-descriptors

Another common use of `exec` is in redirecting file-descriptors. `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` can be redirected to files using exec.

1. Redirecting `stdout` - `exec 1>file` will cause the standard output to be a file named `file` for the end of the current shell session. Anything to output to the display will be in the file.
2. Redirecting `stdin` - It can also be used to redirect the `stdin` to a file. For example, If you want to execute a script file `script.sh`, you can just redirect the `stdin` to the file using `exec 0<script.sh`.

Comment: Okay. Afterwards 'mate-terminal' will have the PID the wrapper-script has? And will use the memory which the wrapper-script used? So the wrapper-script has vanished. Otherwise the two scripts would exist as separate processes on the system (with two different PIDs)?

Comment: @mizech yes. they use same PID

Comment: @mizech Glad to know it helped :)

Comment: Excellent example, that makes it really clear

Comment: This answer is partial and misses one of the important (and typical) uses of `exec` that is it's use in the redirection of file descriptors.

Answer (score 15):

The  `exec`  command replaces the current shell process with the specified command. Normally, when you run a command a new process is spawned (forked). The `exec`  command does not spawn a new process. Instead, the current process is overlaid with the new command. In other words the `exec` command is executed in place of the current shell without creating a new process.

There are three  most common uses of exec command:

#### 1. Replacement of process

***Example-1:***
If you open a new `bash` shell as

```
$ bash
```

in `pstree` it looks like

```
├─gnome-terminal
        ├─bash───bash───pstree
```

The previous `bash` shell is still there and you got a new `bash` shell. Whereas if you open a new bash shell as,

```
$ exec bash
```

the `pstree` shows

```
├─gnome-terminal
        ├─bash───pstree
```

Here the old `bash` is replaced with new one. It is particularly useful to exit from multiple login in one command. **It is more secure and eradicates the chance of leaving an open terminal by mistake.** See [Exit from both root and user with one command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673021/exit-from-both-root-and-user-with-one-command/673024#673024)

***Example-2:*** you can open a file as

```
$ exec vi filename.txt
```

When you quit `vi` there is no need to close the terminal separately as the shell is already replaced. As soon as you close the vi the terminal is also closed.

#### 2. A method of redirection of file descriptors within the shell scripts

The `exec`  command can also be used in shell scripts dynamically open, close, and copy file descriptors. That permits performing redirection of STDIN, STDERR, STDOUT and other file descriptors to various files inside the shell script, instead of command invocation string. If you do not specify a command or arguments, you can specify redirection symbols and file descriptors to perform these functions.

Say you have a shell script `script.sh` you want to have a log file `script.log`, you can use `exec` as,

```
LOG=/path/to/script.log
exec 1>>$LOG
exec 2>&1
```

which is equivalent to

```
./script &>> /path/to/script.log
./script >>  /path/to/script.log 2>&1
```

#### 3. Creating stages of the process using exec command

You can also use the exec  command to create a set of shell scripts that execute one another sequentially like stages of the process. Instead of spawning new processes each time you need to transfer the control to the next script you execute the exec  command .

In this case the last statement of each stage should be `exec` command that invokes the next stage.

See [the uses of the `exec` command in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts) for more.

<sub>**Note:** Part of above is taken from [this.](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/exec.shtml)</sub>

Comment: Only _complete_ answer (so far).

Comment: All the times I have used exec have been for efficiency. If you run a daemon with exec you only need to have one active process instead of two. Leaving the bash process around wastes a couple of MB of ram, amongst other things.

Comment: Easy to understand and complete robust explanation.

Comment: You can combine the two exec statements into one. So, instead of `exec 1>>"$LOG"` then `exec 2>&1`, you can use `exec 1>>"$LOG" 2>&1`. Or, simpler, Bash allows the abbreviated form `exec &>>"$LOG"`. (Side note: Notice the quotations around the file name, in case it contains whitespace.)

Comment: You can also create file descriptors with `exec`. See REDIRECTIONS in the Bash manual for more details. Example: `exec 7>${HOME}/foobar` will allow you to output data there. So, `echo xyzzy >&7` will write the data to `${HOME}/foobar`. To close the file descriptor, use `exec 7>&-`. This can come in useful in more complex cases, e.g. in certain uses of `flock`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know it is also used to redirect file descriptors (for example, STDOUT, STDERR, STDIN) of a bash-script.

So for example, you could read from a file instead from the keyboard by using STDIN redirection and write to a file instead of the terminal by STDOUT (or could be STDERR depending on program) redirection.

Comment: This answer partial and only complements [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/819950/216503).