# im-launch in Ubuntu startup

Tags: startup, startup-applications

I found this im-launch startup entry after installing Ubuntu 19.10 which executes 
`sh -c 'if ! [ -e "/usr/bin/ibus-daemon" ] && [ "x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "xwayland" ] ; then exec env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true; fi'`

I want to know the purpose of this entry and what would happend if i disabled it ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`-e` check the file `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` exists or not? exist means true does not exist means false.

`!` wants to confirm above value is false if above value is true, it will not execute anything.

`[ "x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "xwayland" ]` this can have either one of below values based on how you choose to login at the login screen. which session you will choose x11 or wayland.

`"xx11" = "xwayland"
"xwayland" = "xwayland"`

example output of $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

```
administrator@pratap:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

another example:

```
administrator@pratap:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
administrator@pratap:~$
```

if the first expression is false and x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE = xwayland
then exec the command `env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true`

if the first expression is true or x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE is not equal to xwayland then don't do anything.

see `man test`

```
! EXPRESSION
              EXPRESSION is false
```

and

```
   -e FILE
          FILE exists
```

you can read more about what this command does `then exec env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true;`

see `man env` & man `im-launch`

---

By default in Ubuntu 19.10 `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` exists. so the command will not be executed.

```
env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true
```

when there is the file `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` and my session is `x11`

here is something about IM

[image]

when there is no file `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` and my session is `wayland`

here is the thing which is different from above, which means the env is applied and then a chain reaction followed.

[image]

so, if you disable or enable this from startup list nothing happens unless no existence of this file `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` and your session is `wayland` conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you . I appreciate your detailed  answer for my doubt . People like you makes askubuntu.com awesome .

Comment: Well, I can underdstand the syntax of the command - but in simple words: what does it do in the end? What *is* `im-launch`?

Comment: I know how to use manpages... But `man im-launch` does not enlighten me. It seems very low level. Why does Ubuntu put this into my user-space start programs?

Comment: its kind of thing related to multi languages, keyboard layouts.. specially some kind of chinees, japanees.. etc.

Comment: What I'm most confused about is the `true`. It appears to execute the program passed to it, so in this case it just executes `true`, which doesn't actually do anything. I'm trying to figure out why fcitx doesn't get started, because this startup script doesn't seem to do anything at all. It seems like it should instead run something like `im-launch $GTK_IM_MODULE`, in order to actually start the correct IM method.

Comment: I agree with foobar. I left being puzzled, I had to spend 25 minutes of reading the comment again and again till I get the aha! moment. It is a good, detailed answer, but not a beginner-wise. Thanks anyway for the effort.

Answer (score 5):

I was doing some research on how to configure Ubuntu to make it more performant and ended up here, which is interesting.

My `im-launch` startup entry:

```
sh -c 'if [ "x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "xwayland" ] ; then exec env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true; fi'
```

As answer was detailed by @UnKNOWn but @foobar's comment was my situation, so I took a deep dive.

#### Breaking The Command Down:

`sh` is a command language interpreter that executes commands read from a command line string, the standard input, or a specified file.

`exec` command in Linux is used to execute a command from the bash itself.

`if CONDITION true THEN execute COMMAND`

`im-launch` command is used to start a input method framework server daemon such a ibus-daemon, set up the appropriate environment variables for  the  client  programs,and execute SESSION-PROGRAM such as x-session-manager.

`ibus-daemon` is a daemon program for ibus and it is also a start up program for users to activate ibus daemon, engines and panel.

`daemon` is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user.

`ibus` is an intelligent input bus.

`bus` is simply a set of wires connecting multiple modules (processor, memory, IO devices).

#### The `exec`

Then my question was why do `exec env` when we are already execution the command from `sh`.

The `exec` command replaces the current shell process with the specified command. Normally, when you run a command a new process is spawned (forked), the exec command does not spawn a new process. Instead, the current process is overlaid with the new command. In other words the exec command is executed in place of the current shell without creating a new process.

Use of `env` - If you want to modify the environment for a program before executing the main program, you'd often write an script and at the end of it start the main program. But there is no need for the script to stay in memory at that time. So, exec is used in these cases so that, the main program can replace the mother script.

- [What are possible use of exec command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819910/what-are-possible-use-of-exec-command)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265405/meaning-of-exec-env-command

Answer (score 1):

I have only one thing to add that was hinted by @UnKNOWn and his comment.

*IM-Launch* could mean Input Method. Such as the one referred to [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method)

This also supports Anit's answer by his mentioning ibus future readers can find on wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms)

In plain simple terms it would appear to be a way to check which keyboard layout/language is to be used.. but i wouldn't quote me ...From a google search microsoft has much to say on the subject.

Just thought the 'IM' bit was semi important and above answers weren't clear for me..

Comment: This is a comment not an answer, you should have posted this as such.

Comment: It looks like a valid answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following comment to my im-launch startup item:
"Check for display server type, x11 or wayland"