# restore startup application preferences

Tags: 20.04

I am new to Linux.

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04, opened the GUI startup application preferences window and accidentally removed one of the default 2. I am left with SSH Key agent. How do I restore the other one?

I am not sure, but I think it was im-launch.

Comment: you're right. It's im-launch. The whole command line can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192517/im-launch-in-ubuntu-startup).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387844&p=8713404#post8713404

Long story short, open up a terminal and enter:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/autostart
```

Note: this deletes the other startup applications which didn't come with Ubuntu (i.e. which the user added).

Comment: Removing the remaining startup applications might seem counterintuitive. But once all the user-defined startup apps are removed from the system, the system will restore the original startup apps on the next reboot.